# Composition with android.app.Activity

Tags: android, inheritance, android-activity, composition

The source of wisdom "Effective Java 2nd" says  "Favor composition over inheritance" (item 16).
Now when it comes to Android Activities, it's simple to extends from one but you break encapsulation and the code may break when the superclass is modified.  I tried to compose . Here is the code of the component Activity:

```
public class SimpleActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("This is the Artists tab");
        setContentView(textview);
    }   
}
```

Here is the composed. For each Activity's lifecycle methods, I call the forward methods.

```
public class ComposedActivity extends Activity {
    private SimpleActivity act;
    public ComposedActivity(){
        act = new SimpleActivity();
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        act.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }   
}
```

But the app keeps crashing caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException. 
What am I doing wrong ? Just asking out of curiosity. What do you recommend to expand an Activity without inheritance ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't really have an activity inside another activity. If you want to use composition for Android components, have a look at [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

You can use composition without using fragments simply by factoring your logic into plain Java classes (POJOs) that are not Android components. If they need access to an activity, you can pass a references to the target activity in the constructor. Or better yet, have your activities implement some interface have them hold a reference to it, not to concrete activities.

Comment: Yeah , I looked at fragment but I don't develop for tablets. Or there is ActivityGroup prior to 3.x Thanks for the hint in the last part.

Comment: You can use fragments on pre-Honeycomb devices using the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html). `ActivityGroup` is really only usable in the from of a `TabActivity`. It indeed lets you have multiple activities, one for each tab. It is, however, deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `NullPointerException` because `SimpleActivity.onCreate()` is called directly by `ComposedActivity` while it is supposed to be called thru the use of an `Intent`. So when  `Activity`, superclass of `SimpleActivity`, tries to retrieve the `Intent` that was used to activate it, it finds `null` and crashes as this is unexpected.

On top of this `ComposedActivity` extends `Activity` but you didn't call `super.onCreate()` from `ComposedActivity.onCreate()`. This normally leads the following exception to be thrown:

```
android.app.SuperNotCalledException: 
    Activity did not call through to super.onCreate()
```

But reading your question, this is probably by mistake that `ComposedActivity` extends `Activity`. The way I understood the question, `ComposedActivity` should not inherit from `Activity` but delegate all the `Activity` stuff to `SimpleActivity`.

Anyway, and despite the source of wisdom that Effective Java is, [another source of wisdom](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html#ui) promotes the inheritance from `Activity` as a best practice. More seriously, even if the code we find in tutorials in sometimes questionable, I think inheriting from `Activity` is from far the best way to implement an `Activity`: this was designed that way by Android.

Comment: ComposedActivity is the same type as SimpleActivity, so it extends Activity. I added the super.onCreate()  from ComposedActivity.onCreate(), but still crashes. In fact, I originally suppressed this line. Ok nobody promotes composition of Activity :)

Comment: rather class User seeks Wisdom from EffectiveJava and SO.

Comment: This solves the second problem (`SuperNotCalledException`) but not the first one: `onCreate()` shouldn't be called directly as `Activity` definitely needs being activated by an `Intent`. -- And I like your second comment :)

Comment: if `ComposedActivity` is not an Activity just a POJO , how do you fire it with startActivity and Intent ? . raychenon is an instance of `User` :)

Comment: It is not possible, and this is why doing that way doesn't work: you need a `Context` to fire the `Intent` thru `startActivity()`, and you need to inherit from `Activity` to declare the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file. But inheriting from `Activity`, there's no point in delegating the `Activity` stuff to another class... I think there's no choice actually.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a library supporting composition for Activities and Fragments.
https://github.com/passsy/CompositeAndroid

You have to extend a `CompositeActivity` and than you're able to add plugins which have the same methods to override like the Activity itself.

#### Example

```
public class MainActivity extends CompositeActivity {

    public MainActivity() {
        addPlugin(new DevOptionsPlugin());
    }
}
```

The Plugin adds a item to the options menu and handles the clicks

```
public class DevOptionsPlugin extends ActivityPlugin {

    public static final String DEVELOPER_OPTIONS_TEXT = "Developer options";

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(DEVELOPER_OPTIONS_TEXT);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
        if (DEVELOPER_OPTIONS_TEXT.equals(item.getTitle())) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("mycompany://appname/devoptions"));
            try {
                // note: simply calling startActivity(intent); is not allowed because the call order 
                // would be different. The code before super.startActivity in this plugin would be executed 
                // first before a plugin added later and is more specialized.
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Couldn't open Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            // not calling super!!!
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```